# The heater fan not coming on in my hyundai accent. Car has no A/C option

Tags: hyundai, hvac, heat, accent

No air coming out when I turn the heater on. Turn the fan switch on but no air coming out.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Turn the fan all the way up full, do you get any air then? Have you checked the fuse for the blower?

Comment: do you hear the fan? ie does it make a noise? if it does then if no air either the fan has become detached or the controlling flaps may have failed...

Comment: no do not hear the fan even if I turn it all the way up

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot?  Checked fuses?  Any details you can add will help.  One line questions are hard to solve.

Comment: Have checked the fuse and tried the fan switched on all speed settings..stil no fan sound or air coming out.

Comment: How did you check the fuses? Just visual check or did you test them with a tester or a multimeter? Also, can you add the year/make/model data? That will be helpful with further troubleshooting.

Comment: Can you access the fan motor physically?  Tap it with a hammer gently...If that makes it work for a short time, then the bushes in the motor are worn out.  Then its a cheap job to replace the bushes, however removing the fan motor can take some time (depending on the car)

Answer (score 1):

The basic parts of a blower system are the:

- blower motor
- blower motor resistor
- fuse
- wiring/connectors

Turning your fan switch all the way up should bypass the blower motor resistor, but as you have tried that and it still doesn't work it's unlikely to be the resistor, which leaves the other options. With the fuse, I'd replace it entirely and thoroughly clean the connectors in the fuse panel. Then I'd check the wiring going into the blower itself, disconnect the harness and check to make sure it's clean and reconnect it, seating it properly. Check that the blower is clear of debris and that it spins freely, if it doesn't spin it's seized or jammed. If it spins properly then you can test it by using jumper cables connected to the car battery on one side and probe wires on the other, touching them to the blower connections. If the blower spins then you have a wiring issue somewhere, if it doesn't then the blower itself has failed.